# Any one know how to hack mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_GET['query']))?

Tags: sql-injection, strip-tags

I have one question about SQL injection, this is using strip_tags() inner mysql_real_escape_string().

have you ever try to inject `mysql_real_escape_string`(strip_tags()) code? so the full code would like this one

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE query='".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags())."'";
```

I want to know if that can be safe, because I don't want to change the current code using PDO if it's safe :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL injection that gets around mysql\_real\_escape\_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: yes correct but it will work if you not using strip_tags, the problem now we using strip_tags

Comment: `strip_tags` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` has **absolutely nothing to do neither with sql injections nor with `mysql_real_escape_string`** function, and **utterly irrelevant** to the question.

So, it adds nothing to sql security.

Hope your confusions now cleared and you are going to use prepared statements from now on.

Comment: if i use classic injection like 1' OR 1=1 without strip_tags() the sql injection can be work, but when i add strip_tags() my injection doesn't work. so i need to know another solution how to inject when i use strip_tags inner mysql_real_escape_string